# Render three dimensional JSON list to HTML template in FLASK

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Predictions</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="results">
     <table>
         {% for item in summary %}
             <tr><td>
             {{ item['Name'] }}
             </td></tr>
         {% endfor %}
     </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have three dimensional JSON list which I want to display in the HTML template.
Below is my code and I am not able to identify where am I going wrong. I tried lot of previously answered questions but of no use hence decided to create a new questions but not able to find a solution for three dimensional list.

```
from flask import Flask, abort, request,render_template, json
from DataPreparationv4 import Data_Preprocess
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from flask_jsonpify import jsonpify

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

filename = 'Test2.pkl'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def Predictions():
#Loading Data
    Base_Data = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')

#Calling customized function for data pre process

    DataSet1 = Data_Preprocess(Base_Data)

    CaseNumber = DataSet1[1]
    DataSet1 = DataSet1[0]
#loading the ML Model
    result = loaded_model.predict(DataSet1)

    prob = loaded_model.predict_proba(DataSet1)

#Extracting the probabilities
    Predictions = pd.DataFrame({'CTA Code':result,'Prob1':prob[:,0],'Prob2':prob[:,1]})

# Getting the probability of the prediction
    Predictions['Probability'] = np.where(Predictions['Prob1'] > Predictions['Prob2'], 
               Predictions['Prob1'], Predictions['Prob2'])

    Predictions['CaseNumber'] = CaseNumber['Case Number']

    CTA_Map = [['Y',1],['N',0]]
    CTA_Map = pd.DataFrame(CTA_Map,columns=['CTA Met','CTA Code'],dtype=float)

# Converting the 0 or 1 predictions to "Y" or "N"
    Predictions = pd.merge(Predictions,CTA_Map[['CTA Code','CTA Met']],on='CTA Code', how='left')
    Predictions =  Predictions.drop(['CTA Code','Prob1','Prob2'], axis=1)
    Predictions = Predictions[['CaseNumber', 'CTA Met', 'Probability']]

    #Converting Data frame to list
    df_list = Predictions.values.tolist()


    JSONP_data = jsonpify(df_list)

    return render_template('hello5.html', summary=JSONP_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug = True)
```

Below is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Predictions</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="results">
     <table>
         {% for item in summary %}
             <tr><td>
             {{ item['Name'] }}
             </td></tr>
         {% endfor %}
     </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the below error on the browser:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was
>   unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
>   there is an error in the application.

On Command prompt: I am getting this error.

> File "D:\Cisco_June Data\templates\hello5.html", line 3, in top-level
>   template code
>       {% for item in summary %} TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable

I am looking for a table like this
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WA7q.png)

Example of JSON list in JSONP_data variable:

> [[33314116979, "Y", 1.0], [33319019191, "Y", 1.0], [33317767878, "N",
>   0.8006605339105347], [33314115916, "Y", 0.9613333333333333], [33314000397, "Y", 0.8899768072726529], [33318214829, "N", 1.0]

Requesting your guidance to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the behaviour? What is the expected behaviour? Please give us also an example of JSONP_data.
We must be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Gelineau, as instructed I have added the error which I am getting in browser and anaconda command prompt. Image of the intended output.

Comment: @Gelineau, also the sample of JSONP_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending df_list to your template instead  of calling jsonpify.

jsonpify makes a response object intended to sent by http, not to be iterated on in template 
See stackoverflow.com/questions/7907596/json-dumps-vs-flask-jsonify

Comment: thanks for your guidance. I am able to showcase the list as a list in the html template. Is there any guide/tutorial which I can refer to convert the list a html template or render the dataframe as a table to html template